# MS SQL Server bit column exported as boolean

Tags: sql-server, database, export, export-to-csv, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to export data from SQL Server to flat files.

The data includes a bit column 0/1 and I need it as is but it get exported as Boolean TRUE/FALSE which is causing ETL bulk insert to fail.

[image]

I tried changing the data mapping to single byte integer, float, numeric, string, text hoping to get a simple 0/1 but nothing worked.

Any pointers on how to solve this are appreciated (other than replacing text within the resulted file).

Comment: Is this relevant https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/ssis-truefalse-and-10-values-on-bit-columns/

Comment: Perhaps a case statement on export to cast as INT?

Comment: @scsimon I'm using the export wizard there's no option to add a case statement. Or is there another way to export?

Answer (score 2):

Add a **IIF** in your select to convert **Boolean** to **0/1** to export:

```
SELECT Name, Code
    ,IIF(EuroZone = 1, 1, 0) AS EuroZone
    ,IIF(Visible= 1, 1, 0) AS Visible
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, SQL Server has a bit data type. It does not have a boolean, while SSIS
uses .Net data types, not SQL data types. It supports boolean, not bit. Though it has  built-in conversions, to resolve problems like that. So in my opinion, you need to use a derived column to solve that.